# Windows 10 Parental Controls

Tags: command-line, windows-10, user-accounts, parental-controls

I am trying to limit an account on my computer. It is an admin account (standard account is too restrictive to be useful), not the local admin. I ran:

> Found a way. Just run Command Prompt as administrator, then use the
>   `net` command:
>
> ```
> REM run Command Prompt as administrator
> REM set restrictions net user joe /times:M-F,3pm-9pm;Sa-Su,9am-11am
> REM remove restrictions net user joe /times:all
> REM see current status net user joe
> ```

than did:

> To lock user session after logon hours expire, run the Local Group
>   Policy Editor and set action to take when logon hours expire:
>
> Press Win+R, then type gpedit.msc. Under User Configuration ->
>   Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Logon
>   Options,  click on Set Action to take when logon hours expire. Choose
>   Enabled, then set the action to Lock or Logoff, depending on your
>   needs.

but it seemingly did nothing and user experiences nothing. What am I missing? Is it just because it is an admin account?

Comment: if it is a Microsoft account vs a local account, would that make a difference?.

Comment: Why are you trying to restrict an Administrator account, as an Administrator account, it can remove any restrictions placed on it.

Comment: so would work if standard account?

Comment: if it is a standard account, you can just use the builtin Family Safety tools.

Comment: Perhaps you could make it a power user? Also note, the time can be changed in the BIOS to bypass this. And if the BIOS is PW-protected, there are ways around that, too. Keep that in mind if this is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it using Windows 10 Pro; it did not work with an admin account, but it did work with a standard account.

Answer (score 1):

An administrator account can easily remove any restrictions placed on it.

However, a standard account cannot do this.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to use the builtin Family Safety tools from Microsoft to limit the time and apps that can be used. The downside is that the user does not have admin privileges.

If you need admin, looking for a third-party tool would probably help. (I cannot recommend one because it would be off-topic).

Comment: Microsoft's built-in Family Safety and Parental Control tools for consumers **suck** and always have. They are not even remotely useful security measures. Any kid who knows a little bit about computers can easily bypass these restrictions (trust me). You should look into a more industrial solution like Group Policy, or restrictions inherent into Windows like using `net use` as posted in the question.